# get-pip.py script not running.i am using python 3.2.1.getting the error. i have tried repairing,uninstall/reinstalling everything

Tags: python, pip, python-3.2

here is the error message i am getting while running the script on IDLE.i have downloaded the get-pip.py file from the pypi.org.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 20649, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "c:\users\hp1\appdata\local\temp\tmpjlf6u8\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hp1\appdata\local\temp\tmpjlf6u8\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hp1\appdata\local\temp\tmpjlf6u8\pip.zip\pip\_internal\index.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hp1\appdata\local\temp\tmpjlf6u8\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
  File "c:\users\hp1\appdata\local\temp\tmpjlf6u8\pip.zip\pip\_internal\compat.py", line 61
    return u"".join(u"\\x%x" % c for c in raw_bytes), err.end
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You must read prerequisites before running this script. It is a tool by PyPA, not pypi.org. So you must follow this link: [pip Installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Another thing is it works with these versions (2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6) of python according to official documentation.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct if this solves your problem.

Comment: i am still looking for answer.